# SQL: Insert file name as value (using BULK INSERT)

Tags: sql-server, csv, bulkinsert, sql-server-2017

I am importing several CSV files into a single table (using [BULK INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)). Each CSV file contains information about each department's computers, and are imported monthly into a truncated table.

For billing purposes, I want to track which CSV file each row came from.
Therefore, I'd like to add a column, specifying the file name of each imported file.

Is there an elegant way to achieve this?

*I was thinking about copying the imported data to a second table, and then adding the column information in the process, and truncating the CSV import table after each iteration.*

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2017.

The SQL queries are currently:

```
CREATE TABLE Computere (
Computernavn varchar(255),
Serienummer varchar(255),
Model varchar(255),
OSVersion varchar(255),
OSDBruger varchar(255),
SenesteBruger varchar(255),
SidsteLogon varchar(255)
);

BULK INSERT Computere
FROM '\\server\share\file_for_each_department.csv'
WITH
(
    FORMAT = 'CSV', 
    DATAFILETYPE = 'char',
    FIELDQUOTE = '"',
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a',
    CODEPAGE=65001 ,
    TABLOCK
);
```

Comment: Single `UPDATE Computere SET FilenameColumn = '\\server\share\file_for_each_department.csv' WHERE FilenameColumn IS NULL` after `BULK INSERT ..` may be an option here.

Comment: @Zhorov, I tried something like that, but it gives an error when importing if the number of columns does not match: `Cannot obtain the required interface ("IID_IColumnsInfo") from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".`

Comment: Might be a job for `OPENROWSET(BULK ...)`, as this allows you to customize the ultimate `INSERT` query to include a new column. `BULK INSERT` and `OPENROWSET(BULK ...)` are not completely identical in feature set and behavior, though, so some tinkering may be required.